# Get Values in Array from Json Object

Tags: javascript

I've the following console log:

```
 [{"$id":"1","EmailConfirmedDate":null,"InvitedDate":null,"Username":"abc@bcd.de","Email":"abc@bcd.de","RawPasswordValue":"wC90YmqM1+gFdMAvE2ONAg==E+7bIhf7nBoEmLhs0qn2UAmuzD9cq245gi1Nfr6PvXI=","IsApproved":true,**"Name":"Editor"**,"Avatar":null,"TourData":null,"SessionTimeout":60,"StartContentIds":[],"StartMediaIds":[],"Language":"en-US","Groups":[],"Id":1,"Key":"00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","CreateDate":"2018-06-20T09:27:27.517Z","UpdateDate":"2018-06-20T09:35:57.783Z","HasIdentity":true},{"$id":"2","EmailConfirmedDate":null,"InvitedDate":null,"Username":"SupporterA@umbraco.de","Email":"SupporterA@umbraco.de","RawPasswordValue":"cxEu22do6dAg9gtpNI7THQ==FY0RGPHPWMggVUw++pLL5/sVRzU0syuNSCxbus+6LYw=","IsApproved":true,**"Name":"SupporterA"**,"Avatar":null,"TourData":null,"SessionTimeout":60,"StartContentIds":[],"StartMediaIds":[],"Language":"en-US","Groups":[],"Id":2,"Key":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","CreateDate":"2018-06-20T11:45:41.257Z","UpdateDate":"2018-06-20T11:46:15.53Z","HasIdentity":true}]
```

And I want to get only the Names in an Array. I tried a lot but nothing works.

```
 var suppList = JSON.parse(response.data);

console.log(suppList);
```

I want to output something like supporters = { Editor, SupporterA,.. };

When I do console.log(response.data):

```
[{\"$id\":\"1\",\"EmailConfirmedDate\":null,\"InvitedDate\":null,\"Username\":\"abc@bcd.de\",\"Email\":\"abc@bcd.de\",\"RawPasswordValue\":\"wC90YmqM1+gFdMAvE2ONAg==E+7bIhf7nBoEmLhs0qn2UAmuzD9cq245gi1Nfr6PvXI=\",\"IsApproved\":true,\"Name\":\"Editor\",\"Avatar\".....}]
```

Comment: "I tried a lot but nothing works". What did you try? What was the output from that? What exactly are you looking for and why do you want to achieve it? Are you looking for only the keys to be placed into an array?

Comment: suppList[0].Name,  suppList.Name, suppList['Name'] etc. and always output was undifined

Comment: not the keys but the values from the keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` for this:

```js
const data = [{"$id":"1","EmailConfirmedDate":null,"InvitedDate":null,"Username":"abc@bcd.de","Email":"abc@bcd.de","RawPasswordValue":"wC90YmqM1+gFdMAvE2ONAg==E+7bIhf7nBoEmLhs0qn2UAmuzD9cq245gi1Nfr6PvXI=","IsApproved":true,"Name":"Editor","Avatar":null,"TourData":null,"SessionTimeout":60,"StartContentIds":[],"StartMediaIds":[],"Language":"en-US","Groups":[],"Id":1,"Key":"00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","CreateDate":"2018-06-20T09:27:27.517Z","UpdateDate":"2018-06-20T09:35:57.783Z","HasIdentity":true},{"$id":"2","EmailConfirmedDate":null,"InvitedDate":null,"Username":"SupporterA@umbraco.de","Email":"SupporterA@umbraco.de","RawPasswordValue":"cxEu22do6dAg9gtpNI7THQ==FY0RGPHPWMggVUw++pLL5/sVRzU0syuNSCxbus+6LYw=","IsApproved":true,"Name":"SupporterA","Avatar":null,"TourData":null,"SessionTimeout":60,"StartContentIds":[],"StartMediaIds":[],"Language":"en-US","Groups":[],"Id":2,"Key":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","CreateDate":"2018-06-20T11:45:41.257Z","UpdateDate":"2018-06-20T11:46:15.53Z","HasIdentity":true}]

console.log(data.map(item => item.Name));
```

Comment: I get an error: TypeError: suppList.map is not a function

Comment: You don't need `suppList`. Just use the code I posted.

Comment: this is what I try and the same error occured: const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                console.log(data.map(item => item.Name));

Comment: Sounds like JSON.parse is not producing an array. What are `typeof response.data` and `typeof JSON.parse(response.data)`?

Comment: both String thats the problem I guess :)

Comment: Can you post the exact `response.data` **before JSON.parse** in the question?

Comment: The `response.data` you added starts and ends with 2 double quotes, which makes it invalid JSON. You need to remove the extra quotes before parsing.

Comment: I solved it by changing input of response.data from where I get it, so I got an array and not Json in response.data, then I map the names in a new array..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this way,

```js
var json = [{"$id":"1","EmailConfirmedDate":null,"InvitedDate":null,"Username":"abc@bcd.de","Email":"abc@bcd.de","RawPasswordValue":"wC90YmqM1+gFdMAvE2ONAg==E+7bIhf7nBoEmLhs0qn2UAmuzD9cq245gi1Nfr6PvXI=","IsApproved":true,"Name":"Editor","Avatar":null,"TourData":null,"SessionTimeout":60,"StartContentIds":[],"StartMediaIds":[],"Language":"en-US","Groups":[],"Id":1,"Key":"00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","CreateDate":"2018-06-20T09:27:27.517Z","UpdateDate":"2018-06-20T09:35:57.783Z","HasIdentity":true},{"$id":"2","EmailConfirmedDate":null,"InvitedDate":null,"Username":"SupporterA@umbraco.de","Email":"SupporterA@umbraco.de","RawPasswordValue":"cxEu22do6dAg9gtpNI7THQ==FY0RGPHPWMggVUw++pLL5/sVRzU0syuNSCxbus+6LYw=","IsApproved":true,"Name":"SupporterA","Avatar":null,"TourData":null,"SessionTimeout":60,"StartContentIds":[],"StartMediaIds":[],"Language":"en-US","Groups":[],"Id":2,"Key":"00000002-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","CreateDate":"2018-06-20T11:45:41.257Z","UpdateDate":"2018-06-20T11:46:15.53Z","HasIdentity":true}];
var required = {};
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  required[i] = json[i].Name;
}

console.log(required)
```

Comment: This is what I get when I try this: {0: undefined, 1: undefined, 2: undefined, 3: undefined, 4: undefined, 5: undefined, 6: undefined, 7: undefined, 8: undefined, 9: undefined, 10: undefined, 11: undefined, 12: undefined, 13: undefined, 14: undefined, 15 ....

Comment: Have you tried the `Run code snippet` that I posted here?

Comment: I think something is wrong with your data that you provided

Comment: Yes that can be.